# "aiming to" vs "aimed to be"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm trying to define a goal for my scientific journal paper. What is the proper use of English language and grammar here? Does it make sense in its current form?

> We are running a study towards design of an adaptive framework for energy-efficient streaming of video segments to mobile devices over wireless networks, **which is aimed to be integrated [or aiming to integrate] into DASH.**

Comment: 'Running a study' is less idiomatic than 'conducting a study'. Your query sentence lacks the definite article before 'design' and 'energy-efficient streaming'. I also suggest you replace 'is aimed to be integrated' with 'is intended to be integrated'. Note: only entities that possess volition (i.e. not inanimate or abstract entities) can be 'aiming to' [do something].

Answer (score -1):

This sentence is correct, but could be written better.  "We are" is present tense and "is aimed" is also present tense, even though "aimed" is a past particle.  The sentence would be simplified (and clearer) if "aims", which is present tense, were used instead, as in "which aims to".

BTW, "is aiming to" is present progressive (continuous) and "aiming", in this context, is a present participle.  This tense would also work, but not as well as simple present tense.  The reasons why are rather complicated, so I'll not go into here.

For more information on these tenses see [englishpage.com](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/verbtenseintro.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your answer is muddled and can only be less than helpful to the questioner.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the final suggested revise then?

Comment: Bottom line, "which is aimed to be".

In my reply, I said "which aims to be" was the best, but that the other were acceptable.  However, looking over the sentence again, I see that the two choices, "which aims to" and "which is aiming to", are saying that the framework is doing the aiming.  That is not the case.  The framework is what is being aimed, so the correct form is "which is aimed."